# SWT image button on Mac not working

Tags: java, eclipse, image, button, swt

So i have a button w/ an image using SWT.
The code for it's design is here:

`final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.FLAT | SWT.CENTER);
    button.setBounds(54, 121, 109, 33);
    button.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(LoginDialog.class,
        "SignInButton.png"));`

I want to Have the image take up the whole button with no borders like i can in windows. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

here is an image of what it looks like atm:
[image]

Essentially i just want the white parts gone.

Comment: Don't use `setBounds` - use a [layout](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) so that the button can work out its own size. I don't think the border can be removed on Mac buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, `Button` isn't the best starting point if you basically want to *draw* a completely different type of button. You can however, create your own widget using [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm) tutorial. I wrote an example here:

```
public class ImageButton extends Composite
{
    private Color   textColor;
    private Image   image;
    private String  text;
    private int     width;
    private int     height;

    public ImageButton(Composite parent, int style)
    {
        super(parent, style);

        textColor = Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);

        /* Add dispose listener for the image */
        addListener(SWT.Dispose, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                if (image != null)
                    image.dispose();
            }
        });

        /* Add custom paint listener that paints the stars */
        addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e)
            {
                paintControl(e);
            }
        });

        /* Listen for click events */
        addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                System.out.println("Click");
            }
        });
    }

    private void paintControl(Event event)
    {
        GC gc = event.gc;

        if (image != null)
        {
            gc.drawImage(image, 1, 1);
            Point textSize = gc.textExtent(text);
            gc.setForeground(textColor);
            gc.drawText(text, (width - textSize.x) / 2 + 1, (height - textSize.y) / 2 + 1, true);
        }
    }

    public void setImage(Image image)
    {
        this.image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), image, SWT.IMAGE_COPY);
        width = image.getBounds().width;
        height = image.getBounds().height;
        redraw();
    }

    public void setText(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
        redraw();
    }

    @Override
    public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed)
    {
        int overallWidth = width;
        int overallHeight = height;

        /* Consider hints */
        if (wHint != SWT.DEFAULT && wHint < overallWidth)
            overallWidth = wHint;

        if (hHint != SWT.DEFAULT && hHint < overallHeight)
            overallHeight = hHint;

        /* Return computed dimensions plus border */
        return new Point(overallWidth + 2, overallHeight + 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        ImageButton button = new ImageButton(shell, SWT.NONE);
        button.setImage(new Image(display, "button.png"));
        button.setText("Button");

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

---

Of course you'd have to take care of different states like `pressed`, `hover` and so on.

Comment: Oh I see, this will really help me in my project thank you. Kinda wish swt mac buttons would work like the windows buttons though. =/